# How to increase vertical tab width for icon visibility and click reach?

Tags: reactjs, web-applications, material-ui

I've been trying to increase the width of my tab click range to expand its reach and to be able to view icons.

I've seen a few examples suggesting to create a class with different props. It worked with a horizontal tab but not a vertical one. It would be great if anyone could help out. I've tried also searching for vertical tabs props specifically in material UI with no results, unfortunately. Thanks for helping

Here is how it currently looks:

[image: Menu with icons]

Code:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Tabs from "@material-ui/core/Tabs";
import Tab from "@material-ui/core/Tab";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Home from './Screens/Home'
import home from './home.svg';
import Contact from './Screens/Contact'
import contact from './contact.svg';
import {Router} from 'react-router-dom'
import Chat from './Screens/Chat'
import chat from './chat.svg';
import Settings from './Screens/Settings'
import settings from './settings.svg'
import Logout from './Screens/Logout'
import logout from './logout.svg';export default class ProfileTabs 

extends React.PureComponent {
  state = { activeIndex: 0 };

  handleChange = (_, activeIndex) => this.setState({ activeIndex });
  render() {

    const { activeIndex } = this.state;
    return (
        <nav className= "side-drawer">
      <div style={{letterSpacing: 0.7, left: 70, position: "absolute", marginTop: 40}}>
        <VerticalTabs value={activeIndex} onChange={this.handleChange}>
          <MyTab  icon ={<img className= "home" src={home}  alt="home" style={{height: 45, left:-35, top:8, position: "absolute"}}/>}
          label={<p style={{ textTransform:"capitalize"}}>
          Home
          </p>} 
          />
          <MyTab icon ={<img className= "process" src={process}  alt="process" style={{height: 45, left:-40, top:4, position: "absolute"}}/>}
          label={<p style={{textTransform:"capitalize"}}>
          Contact
          </p>} 
          />
          <MyTab icon={<img className= "design" src={design}  alt="design" style={{height: 45, left:-40, top:6, position: "absolute"}}/>}
          label={<p style={{textTransform:"capitalize"}}>
         Chat
          </p>} 
          />
          <MyTab icon = {<img className= "material" src={material}  alt="material" style={{height: 45, left:-40, top:5, position: "absolute"}}/>}
          label={<p style={{textTransform:"capitalize"}}>
         Settings
          </p>} 
          />
          <MyTab icon={
<img className= "printer" src={printer}  alt="printer" style={{height: 45, left:-40, top:8, position: "absolute"}}/>}
          label={<p style={{textTransform:"capitalize"}}>
          Logout
          </p>} 
          />
        </VerticalTabs>



        {activeIndex === 0 && <TabContainer><Home/></TabContainer>}
        {activeIndex === 1 && <TabContainer><Processes/></TabContainer>}
        {activeIndex === 2 && <TabContainer><Designs/></TabContainer>}
        {activeIndex === 3 && <TabContainer><Materials/></TabContainer>}
        {activeIndex === 4 && <TabContainer><Printers/></TabContainer>}


      </div>
      </nav>
    );
  }
}

const VerticalTabs = withStyles(theme => ({
  flexContainer: {
    flexDirection: "column"
  },
  indicator: {
    display: "none"

  }
}))(Tabs);

const MyTab = withStyles(theme => ({
  selected: {
    color: "White",
    borderRight: "none"

  }
}))(Tab);


const styles = theme => ({

  root: {
    minWidth: 100,
  },
});

function TabContainer(props) {
  return (
    <Typography component="div" style={{ padding: 9 * 3 }}>
      {props.children}
    </Typography>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<ProfileTabs />, rootElement);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone interested I've solved it:

increase the minWidth on styles.root
and move icons by adding position: "absolute" to their styles